# Creating a background image on the title page only using Beamer

Tags: beamer

I am attempting to construct a Beamer presentation and I'm experiencing some difficulty. While I can insert a background image on the title slide using a "global setting", I don't want it to appear on every subsequent slide. Every subsequent slide (including the navigation/menu slide) should have a completely blue background with text of a currently undetermined color. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

% \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=yellow}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg={}}
\title[...]{My title}

\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{08171830.jpg}}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\date{}

\begin{document}

    \AtBeginSection[]
    {
        \usebackgroundtemplate{}
        \begin{frame}
            \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[default]
            \frametitle{Outline}
            \tableofcontents[currentsection]
        \end{frame}
    }

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage

    \end{frame}

    \section{Introduction}

    \usebackgroundtemplate{}
    \begin{frame}{History}
        This is a test page!
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. Also you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `\setbeamertemplate{title page}{...}` you can modify the title page without effecting global setting.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\pgfdeclareimage[height=\paperheight]{mybackground}{example-image-duck}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{

        \begin{picture}(0,0)

            \put(-30,-163){%
                \pgfuseimage{mybackground}
            }

            \put(0,-110.7){%
                \begin{minipage}[b][45mm][t]{226mm}
                    \usebeamerfont{title}{\inserttitle\par}
                \end{minipage}
            }

            \end{picture}

    }

\title[...]{My title}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \section{Introduction}

    \begin{frame}{History}
        This is a test page!
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using \usebackgroundtemplate{} just before \begin{frame} worked for me.

Comment: @Hirak If you have an alternative solution, please consider positing it as an answer, more people will see it.

Comment: @Hirak: that puts it on every slide, not?

Comment: The answer from @user43791 is better: it adds a background as a new layer while preserving the title-slide template. This solution discards printing of subtitles, authors, dates, and overrides the Beamer template's title-slide formatting.

Comment: How to remove the navigation symbols in the title page?

Comment: @Stephen If you have a new question, please ask a new question

Answer (score 19):

Enclosing `\usebackgroundtemplate` by `{ ... }` applies the command within the scope. Place your title page frame within the scope like so:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\title[...]{My title}
\begin{document}
{
  \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{back.pdf}}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{History}
    This is a test page!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Beamer version 3.40**

I had success with using `\setbeamertemplate{background}{...}`. Note the use of the encompassing braces seen after the `\title` line. This serves to limit the background image to just the title slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\begin{document}

\title[...]{My title}

{
  \setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{back.pdf}}

  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{History}
    This is a test page!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use tikz to set a background image with absolute positioning and wrap it in `\addtobeamertemplate{title page}` which can be done from the header or a style file.

```
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[above right,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south west)
    {
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background.jpg}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}{}
```

The tikz code comes from this article on making title slides https://latex-beamer.com/tutorials/beautiful-title-slide/