# Author and institute don't appear when adding background image to title page in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am attempting to add a background image to the title page of a beamer talk. I have attempted to use the solution given here [Creating a background image on the title page only using Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168757/creating-a-background-image-on-the-title-page-only-using-beamer). However I am getting some problems I don't understand. Here is my MWE .

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine} % or any other font package (or none)
\newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}} % selects Libertine for quote font
\usepackage{tikz}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{mybackground}{bigdata410}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{   
        \begin{picture}(0,0) 
            \put(-30,-163){%
                \pgfuseimage{mybackground}
            } 
            \put(0,-110.7){%
                \begin{minipage}[b][45mm][t]{226mm}
                    \usebeamerfont{title}{\inserttitle\par}
                \end{minipage}
            }  
            \end{picture}
    } 
\title{Lost in data}
\author[Author et al.\@]{Author}
\institute{University of }
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My problems are

- The title is not centered
- The author and institution don't appear on the title page
- If I comment out the libertine fonts lines I get

  LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available
  (Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 44.

  (I can fix this last problem using \usepackage{lmodern} it seems but I am not sure I like that font.)

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a background image on the title page only using Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168757/creating-a-background-image-on-the-title-page-only-using-beamer)

Comment: @Johannes_B Oh I should have said that is where I started and then I got the problems I described. That example also doesn't have the title centered and doesn't have author or institution. I am not what I am doing wrong as I pretty much copied it verbatim.

Comment: Well, the first two issues are due to your current definition of the `title page` template; with your current settings the title won't be centered; furthermore, you don't include author nor institution on the template so obviously they don't appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is to add an image in the background for the title page, the method described in the linked answer is not the most appropriate one, since setting the `title page` template demands setting all the elements of the template and their attributes (which is part of your problem (see below)).

A more convenient approach is to locally (inside a group) set the `background canvas` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white}

\title{The title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{mushrooms}}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you, however, want to completely change the title page template by setting the template from scratch, then:

1. Your title is not centered because your current settings don't tell LaTeX that you want it centered; in fact, the `minipage` you are using for the title is way too big, as you can see by temporarily disabling the colors and framing it:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{libertine} % or any other font package (or none)
   \newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}} % selects Libertine for quote font
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
   \setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
   \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

   %\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
   %\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

   \pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{mybackground}{bigdata410}

   \setbeamertemplate{title page}{   
           \begin{picture}(0,0) 
               \put(-30,-163){%
       %            \pgfuseimage{mybackground}
               } 
               \put(0,-110.7){%
               \centering
                   \frame{\begin{minipage}[b][45mm][t]{226mm}
                   \centering
                       \usebeamerfont{title}{\inserttitle\par}
                   \end{minipage}}
               }  
               \end{picture}
       } 
   \title{Lost in data}
   \author[Author et al.\@]{Author}
   \institute{University of }
   \date{}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
     \titlepage
   \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   Change `226mm` to `\textwidth` and use `\centering` inside the `minipage`:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{libertine} % or any other font package (or none)
   \newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}} % selects Libertine for quote font
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
   \setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
   \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

   %\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
   %\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

   \pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{mybackground}{bigdata410}

   \setbeamertemplate{title page}{   
           \begin{picture}(0,0) 
               \put(-30,-163){%
       %            \pgfuseimage{mybackground}
               } 
               \put(0,-110.7){%
                   \frame{\begin{minipage}[b][45mm][t]{\textwidth}
                       \centering
                       \usebeamerfont{title}{\inserttitle\par}
                   \end{minipage}}
               }  
               \end{picture}
       } 
   \title{Lost in data}
   \author[Author et al.\@]{Author}
   \institute{University of }
   \date{}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
     \titlepage
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   Perhaps you also want to reduce the height?
2. There's no title nor institution since your settings for the title page template don't have the corresponding inserts; where do you want this information to appear? Use `\insertauthor`, `\insertinstitution` at the desired locations. For example:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{libertine} % or any other font package (or none)
   \newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}} % selects Libertine for quote font
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
   \setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
   \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

   \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
   \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

   \pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{mybackground}{bigdata410}

   \setbeamertemplate{title page}{   
           \begin{picture}(0,0) 
               \put(-30,-163){%
                   \pgfuseimage{mybackground}
               } 
               \put(0,-110.7){%
                   \frame{\begin{minipage}[b][45mm][t]{\textwidth}
                       \centering
                       \usebeamerfont{title}{\inserttitle\par}\vfill
                       \usebeamerfont{author}{\insertauthor\par}\vfill
                       \usebeamerfont{institute}{\insertinstitute\par}
                   \end{minipage}}
               }  
               \end{picture}
       } 
   \title{Lost in data}
   \author[Author et al.\@]{Author}
   \institute{University of }
   \date{}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
     \titlepage
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   Once you are happy with the settings, delete (or comment out) the `\frame` command:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{libertine} % or any other font package (or none)
   \newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}} % selects Libertine for quote font
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
   \setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
   \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

   \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
   \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}

   \pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{mybackground}{bigdata410}

   \setbeamertemplate{title page}{   
           \begin{picture}(0,0) 
               \put(-30,-163){%
                   \pgfuseimage{mybackground}
               } 
               \put(0,-110.7){%
                   \begin{minipage}[b][45mm][t]{\textwidth}
                       \centering
                       \usebeamerfont{title}{\inserttitle\par}\vfill
                       \usebeamerfont{author}{\insertauthor\par}\vfill
                       \usebeamerfont{institute}{\insertinstitute\par}
                   \end{minipage}%
               }  
               \end{picture}
       } 
   \title{Lost in data}
   \author[Author et al.\@]{Author}
   \institute{University of }
   \date{}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
     \titlepage
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
3. There are several ways to remedy this warning; load a font containing the missing font size (`lmodern`, for example) or use `\let\Tiny\tiny`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Especially as for at least one of the problems I now see I was being a bit stupid.

Comment: How can I adjust just the size/color of the title "Lost in data" without changing the font size/color of Author etc.

Comment: @felix Use `\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red,bg=blue}` and `\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Huge}` (change the attributes according to your needs).