# How to set a beamer theme with multiple background images on a beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, formatting, backgrounds, themes

I've been trying to make my own theme with 2 different background images and haven't succeed.

I have two images:

- A title image one

  ```
  {
    \usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth] 
     {img/titleimage.png}}
    \begin{frame}
     \vspace*{80pt}
     \hspace*{1em}
  \titlepage
    \end{frame}
  }
  ```
- An image for the rest of the slides (don't know how to do it!)

I want to set this on the theme and not on the main script.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information? For which situations do you want different background images? You can always just change the background template in-between frames...

Comment: Please provide us with a short version of what you have tried.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459177/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170118/36296

Comment: Those posts only contain the answer to the title page image but I want to set another backgrounf for the remaining slides.

Comment: @Paula For normal slides: `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}}`